# ffmpeg pixel format definitions

Tags: ffmpeg, colorspace

`ffmpeg -pix_fmts` lists many pixel formats. In my ffmpeg, there are 66 different pixel formats that start with *yuv*. A few of them are familiar to me (e.g., yuv422p), but most of them are not (e.g., yuva422p16be).

Where are these pixel formats defined?

Comment: Most are self describing. yuva422p16be YUV are luma and chroma planes. a is the alpha channel. 422 is the plan size descriptions, p means planer, 16be means 16 bits per pixel big endian format.

Comment: Thanks @SlimSCSI. Do you know what the j stands for in yuvj440p?

Comment: YUV420P uses the range 16 to 239 to describe luminance and chroma values, so values from 0 to 16 get mapped to the same output level, as do values 239-255. YUVJ420P uses the full range from 0 to 255. Not sure why it's J though.

Comment: In `libavutil/pixfmt.h`: `AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ420P,  ///< planar YUV 4:2:0, 12bpp, full scale (JPEG), deprecated in favor of AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P and setting color_range`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your question was

> Where are these pixel formats defined?

Go to http://ffmpeg.org/download.html and download the source of ffmpeg. Then unpack it

```
tar -xavf FILENAME.tar.*
```

and descend to the folder in the source code that is called `libavutil`

```
cd ffmpeg-*/libavutil/
```

and open the file `pixfmt.h` where you will find a description of all pixel formats. **A few sample lines**

```
AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,   ///< planar YUV 4:2:0, 12bpp, (1 Cr & Cb sample per 2x2 Y samples)          
AV_PIX_FMT_YUYV422,   ///< packed YUV 4:2:2, 16bpp, Y0 Cb Y1 Cr
AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,     ///< packed RGB 8:8:8, 24bpp, RGBRGB...
AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24,     ///< packed RGB 8:8:8, 24bpp, BGRBGR...
AV_PIX_FMT_YUV422P,   ///< planar YUV 4:2:2, 16bpp, (1 Cr & Cb sample per 2x1 Y samples)
```

Additionally you can read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV and it’s cited sources and external links.

Comment: Or just visit https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/pixfmt_8h_source.html

Comment: Or http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libavutil/pixfmt.h;hb=HEAD

Comment: Or https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavutil/pixfmt.h